# undefined index

Tags: php, database

Is there any wrong with this statement?

Error return:

> Notice: Undefined index: inputBlock
>
> Notice: Undefined index: inputHouseUnit

code:

```
if($conn){
    $insertData = "INSERT INTO ESTATEUNIT (BLOCK, UNIT) VALUES ('$_POST[inputBlock]', '$_POST[inputHouseUnit]')";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` directly, unvalidated in your queries.

Comment: It says you dont have a key in $_POST with those names -> Check if any thing is here in your `$_POST`, I think execution these codes happens before posting

Comment: you can try `' or '1'='1' /* '` or `;DROP TABLE tablename` its really amazing i mean your code is vulnerable to sql injection please escape all request if you dont let want other to pow3ed your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insertData = "INSERT INTO ESTATEUNIT (BLOCK, UNIT) VALUES ('".$_POST['inputBlock']."', '".$_POST['inputHouseUnit']."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP array indices are either numbers or strings.

If `inputBlock` and `inputHouseUnit` are the identifiers of string variables, you must precede them with `$` (e.g., `$_POST[$inputBlock]`).

If they are literal strings, wrap them in `'` (single-quotes) or `"` (double-quotes) (e.g., `$_POST["inputBlock"]`).

Obviously, you will have to be careful of escaping single and double quotes. Also, you should validate your user input before attempting to put it into the database.

Comment: What do you categorize the name of a text field?

Comment: @Bryan Sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: inputBlock is the name/id of a text field. In this case, is it consider as literal string?

Comment: Yes, it's a literal string then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It should look like this

```
if($conn){
    $insertData = "INSERT INTO ESTATEUNIT (BLOCK, UNIT) VALUES ('" . $_POST["inputBlock"] . "', '" . $_POST["inputHouseUnit"] . "')";
}
```

I used string concatination so you wouldn't have to escape the quotes.

You should also think about the security as passing raw post data into database is very unsafe - never trust your user.

Comment: Why was everyone on this question down voted with no apparent reason or a comment on why this has been done?

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are wrong. And even contradicts with the question, where apparently stated that `inputBlock` is recognized as array index.

> Is there any wrong with this statement?

Nope. Your statement is perfectly valid.

The reason why you getting these messages is empty $_POST array. most likely you're calling this code with GET method.

Put your code into this if statement:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Also, you have to always format your query properly. At least the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15614086/285587)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these vars are being fed from the

$_POST[inputBlock]
$_POST[inputHouseUnit]

Give a print on them before the $sql.

Also, make sure your  has a method=POST specified. If it doesn't have, these vars will be brought as GET.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values of individual post operations in separate variables and then use them in the `echo` function...like this...

```
$x=$_POST[inputBlock];
<br>$y=$_POST[inputHouseUnit];
```

And then substitute the variables in the `echo` function....

Also check if the post method is receiving any value or not beacuse you might have just send only one value to your php page...
undefined index is often countered when a variable doesn't get any value from `$_POST` array.